# Solidity 0.5.0: TypeError Initial value for constant variable has to be compile-time constant

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Why can't I declare a constant this way in Solidity 0.5.0? With recent versions everything went fine:

```
uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals()));

/**
 * @return the number of decimals of the token.
 */
function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
    return _decimals;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solidity, constants aren't stored in storage anywhere; they're substituted in the bytecode. Roughly, something like this:

```
constant uint256 FOO = 42;

function blah() {
    return FOO;
}
```

Turns into this:

```
function blah() {
    return 42;
}
```

The compiler can only do this substitution if the value of the constant is known *at compile time*. In your example, if `_decimals` is a constant, it's theoretically possible for a compiler to figure out that `decimals()` returns a constant and what that value is, but the Solidity compiler is nowhere near that smart.